# LEDs to illuminate underside of king bed

Tags: led

I purchased a king sized bed that was designed in the 1980s, and it was lit from underneath.   I thought that the bed was arriving with this lighting still in place, but the lighting was evidently removed some time ago.  I want to add lighting, to get the effect I thought would already be in place.   My vision is pretty simple:  White lights under three sides of the bed, set to a timer for a couple of hours at night and an hour in the morning.

I know almost nil about lighting.  I would appreciate advice regarding ways to do this project.   I have seen a few posts and blogs about ways to do this, but most that I've found focus on getting the lowest cost, and safety seems overlooked.    Also, a lot of the posts are a few years old, and I wonder if newer products are available since those posts were created.

I am keeping my fingers crossed that it will be simple, but it will be what it will be…   I am willing to hire someone, if needed.   Thanks in advance for any guidance you can lend.

Comment: Ariel, thank you very much for the helpful and prompt reply!

Answer (score 2):

Buy 12V LED strip lighting. Google: 3528 5050 5630 5730 7020 SMD Strip LED. (Pick one number and google that, not all at once.) eBay is a great place to get it.

The bigger the number the brighter the light, but since you probably want an entire strip running the length of the bed you might not want a bright one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMD_LED_Module

They are sold by the meter, or the reel - try to buy one long enough to do all 3 sides in one run.

Don't forget a power supply - make sure it's powerful enough, the strip lighting is rated in Watts (or Amps) per meter. You can pug it into a simple wall timer.

Some of them come with pre-attached sticky tape on the back. You may want to consider getting a waterproof one if the LEDs will be exposed since the waterproofing also protects it from anyone touching it.

Comment: What about the timer?

Comment: Ariel already said that the power supply can be plugged into a simple wall timer. I second that for simplicity.